# Не работает callback_query_handler(), подскажите почему ? Использую библиотеку aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup

API_TOKEN = '6894198454:AAGSgT3fxyCbjpHAesCrIpM0Eax3fcqfG-s'

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

kb_1 = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)

but1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="ИСиТ", callback_data="isit")
but2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="ИБ", callback_data="ib")
but3 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="ТФ", callback_data="tf")
but4 = InlineKeyboardButton(text="РФ", callback_data="rf")

kb_1.add(but1, but2, but3, but4)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text="Привет первокурсник! Какое у тебя направление?", reply_markup=kb_1)



@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def naprav_callback(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
   await bot.send_message(chat_id=callback.from_user.id, text='123')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: А для чего ты инлайн кнопки вносишь в реплай клавиатуру? Кнопки в реплай клавиатурах - это просто текст, за исключением нескольких специальных кнопок, у них нет callback_data. Обрабатывать такие кнопки нужно как обычные сообщения

Comment: понял, спасибо )